# customize django form validation

Tags: python, django, validation, django-forms

I have the [django validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/validation/) of my form.py where in some cases the validation must be over-ridden.

I have some code that I cannot see why the validation code is not working as I had expected. This is killing me b/c I cannot see the issue.

The following code, when the if condition is true, should raise the validation error. When false, the code should remove the text entered by the user and submit the form. The current action is that the false condition is not entered.

Here is my code: **UPDATED TO INCLUDE NAMED TUPLE**

```
def clean(self):

    ADDRESS_FIELDS = {
        0: AddressFields(LocalityDisplay=True, LocalityRequired=False, RegionDisplay=True, RegionRequired=False, PostcodeDisplay=True, PostcodeRequired=False),
        ............
        253: AddressFields(LocalityDisplay=False, LocalityRequired=False, RegionDisplay=True, RegionRequired=True, PostcodeDisplay=False, PostcodeRequired=False),
        ............
    }
    .......

    if atype_config.LocalityRequired: 

        if 'name_of_field' in cd_addf and len(cd_addf['name_of_field'].strip()) == 0:
            self._errors['name_of_field'] = self.error_class([_("This field is required.")])

    else: # do this when false.

        self.cleaned_data.pop('name_of_field', None) #  remove the entered value.
```

Comment: "The current action is that the false condition is not entered" ... you need to look at the condition and, since it seems to be the crux of the problem, update the question with code that includes the condition.

Comment: mhawke, I have updated my code. I have checked the code and it is # 253 of mt named tuple that is selected and should return false. I also tried if not atype_config.LocalityRequired:, but this gave me the same issue.

Comment: Well, it can't be both true _and_ false at the same time, i.e. one of `atype_config.LocalityRequired` or `not atype_config.LocalityRequired` _must_ be false. Are you sure that `atype_config` is being set to a named tuple with `LocalityRequired` set to false? Try adding some debug/print statements to print out what `atype_config` is set to, as well as show which branch of the if statement is take.

Comment: One other thing. Are you sure that your `clean()` function is even being called? If not, that might explain the behaviour that you are seeing. Try adding some debugging to `clean()`.